# Surround a responsive image with divs

Tags: javascript, css, html, responsive-design

I have an image that I want to center in the middle of a div, the div can grow and shrink according to the size of the window, the image can also differ in size and should never be larger than the surrounding div.

I have managed to do this by using the following HTML:

```
<div class="imgspace">
  <img src="/variable.jpeg">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.imgspace {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0; 
  right: 0;
}

.imgspace img {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Now I want to implement a simple set of controls for the image. They should be layed out in three divs surrounding the image on the left, bottom and right side. The divs should grow and shrink with the image as it changes, both considering viewport size changes as well as actual image size.

Is this possible to achieve using only CSS or do I have to involve javascript?

Here's the starting point [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dotmartin/6q4Ls/1/). I have intentionally left out the three surrounding divs since the placement in the DOM does not matter for me.

Comment: JSfiddle please...I'm having trouble visualising the HTML as it seems that your .imgspace div is for a full page.

Comment: It is not for a full page, but it could very well be. The surrounding div is also position absolute with edges set to a fixed number of rems. I've not used jsfiddle before. But I'll try to get a demo working.

Comment: The image will cover the div based on your CSS...is that intentional? That being the case, why would you center it...it doesn't seem logical

Comment: When the image is smaller than the available space it should be centered.

Comment: But your Image CSS won't do that at the moment. Is the size of the div related to the size of the image? Js is going to be a factor here I suspect....you have too many unknown variables at play.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to reserve some space for left, right and bottom elements.

In my example, I am reserving 10% for the `#left` and `#right` elements, leaving the `img` with a width 80%. Also, reserved 10% height for the `#bottom` element.

Hopefully this is what you are looking for: [**http://jsfiddle.net/6q4Ls/2/**](http://jsfiddle.net/6q4Ls/2/)
Drag the separators to see how the elements react.

---

Another solution using elements outside your container, that seems simpler:
[**http://jsfiddle.net/6q4Ls/5/**](http://jsfiddle.net/6q4Ls/5/)

---

**Edit**
Using fixed size [**http://jsfiddle.net/6q4Ls/9/**](http://jsfiddle.net/6q4Ls/9/)

This might not work in all browsers, as I am using the [calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) function.

```
div.imgspace img {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: calc(100% - 200px);
  max-height: calc(100% - 100px);
  top: 0; right: 100px; bottom: 100px; left: 100px;
}
```

Comment: The bottom controls needs to be fixed height and the sidebars needs to be fixed width. That might be an easier case. The outside solution is simpler, but not what the designer wants.. :)

Comment: @dotmartin Check my new solution for fixed size sidebars.

Comment: Very interesting! The controls should surround the image, but I think I can use this somehow.